# FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject : Need a solution for this

Tags: apex, webservices, apex-webservice

I was working on the trailhead challenge https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

The Apex class AccountManager is shown below:

[image]

The Test class named AccountManagerTest for the above code is shown below:
[image]

The test class has 100% code coverage but the challenge is getting failed with the reason:
There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject.

The log file generates two operation( one Status- success and after some moment-Status is "List has no rows for assignment to SObject".

[image]

Comment: Try making sure the user verifying the challenge has View All permission on the Account object.

Comment: Open the log that has the error and check the box Debug Only underneath the log contents and left of the filter textbox. Make sure your debugs are returning expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently completed this trailhead module. I think you have incorrectly mentioned urlMapping. As urlMapping is case sensitive, use small 'c' in 'contacts' as mentioned in challenge. Url mapping for AccountManager class is mentioned below-

@RestResource(urlMapping='/Accounts/*/contacts')

Answer (score 0):

Test your query. Are you in an environment with data? If you are in a new scratch org or developer sandbox it may not have data until you create some, thus the error you cited. You could consider using apex mocks or creating data in the environment to workaround the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a trigger or something that is causing the error. 
I suggest testing in a brand new org or after reading the debug log search for Trigger/Process Builder causing the error. 
I see that your code is right and only one log record should have been generated after testing the scenario.

You can see if you open the raw log, that this is the anonymous code that they are running

`for (Account account: [select id, (select id from contacts) from account]) { 
    if (account.contacts.size() > 1) { 
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        req.requestUri = '/services/apexrest/Accounts/'+account.id+'/contacts'; 
        req.httpMethod = 'GET'; 
        RestContext.request = req; 
        Account accountFromRestCall = AccountManager.getAccount(); 
        Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>([select id from contact where accountId = :account.Id]); 
        System.assert(true, contacts.containsKey(accountFromRestCall.contacts[0].Id));
        break; 
    } 
 }`

So you can check if the second log record is indeed a log from Trailhead

Comment: The code is returning one Id and getting successful. But the problem is that as soon as I hit the verify challenge in the trailhead,another log will get generated with message in the logs as " list has no rows for assignment to sObject",as shown in the screenshot above.